# Network icon suddenly gone, can't access wifi hotspot

Tags: networking

Today, for no reason I can discern, the network indicator icon is missing. I happen to also be away from home in a business trip, so I am reliant on wifi hotspots for internet access.

Since the icon isn't there, I can't connect to wifi, and if I can't connect to the internet, I can't take usual actions like re installing any network related packages or searching on my laptop for solutions.

I'm asking this question via my phone, which I also can't use to connect my laptop to the internet because even when I try using USB tethering, there seems to be no internet connection.

How do I get my network icon back and reconnect to the internet?